# Set Layout Preview API in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

---

I read on JetBrains's page that "You can also preview the layout on all installed Android API versions."

I'm trying to show layout preview API 21 and API 16 (Android 4.1 SDK is already installed)

Android studio is just showing API 21-22-23. How can add API 16 also?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. Android SDK Platform is not enough alone for preview. You need to install System images also. I missed the images. Be sure, "show package details" checkbox is checked. Then you can install system images.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, you only need one of the system images, not both/all

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just add the Api versions you want to support.

**Edit**:
Try adding a new device with the api version you're looking to preview.

[image]

Comment: I have already installed on SDK Manager. You can see on first picture.  That's the problem. :)

Comment: I know, you're talking about emulator not "layout preview". I found answer. Thank you. I'm updating